# Spatial Pyramid Pooling in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I read a research paper on [Spatial Pyramid Pooling](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729.pdf). Here's an implementation of  [SPP](https://github.com/Sarthak-02/keras-spp/blob/master/SpatialPyramidPooling.py). I added the SPP layer in my neural network, but I dont know how to feed the images with original dimensions to my CNN. Since I can't store different sizes of images in an array, how would I feed the images with original dimension to my CNN. Like can I have the array of image dimension `[depth,height,width]` as `[3,None,None]` ?

Comment: Here is a Keras implementation: https://github.com/yhenon/keras-spp